# PHP Select Where Date Equals DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a website where posts are recorded in a MySQL Table with an `Added` value, which is set to DateTime. An example of a stored value is `2016:12:12 15:30:21`.

So I now want to build a page which selects all records of a certain date, using a php script and URL paramater like `added.php?date=2016-12-12`.

So my php script for this would be:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["date"])){
        $date = $_GET["date"];
    } else {
        header("Location: $site_url");
        exit();
    };
?>
```

How do I now actually select the rows with this date? I'm trying to use:

```
$rows_sql = "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE added = '$date';
```

But this isn't working. Any ideas how I can get this working in the format I have?

Comment: Are you asking for help querying the database with this date? Your PHP doesn't really do much of anything.....  Can you post the relevant parts of whatever file `$site_url` is supposed to reference?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Beside missing the closing quotes ("), this query will work. You should post the actual code where you send it to the database however.

Comment: if $date= 2016-12-12, you have to select all the values that are bigger than: 2016-12-12 00:00:00 and smaller than 2016-12-12 23:59:59 or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please change your query line as below:

```
$rows_sql = "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE Date(added) = '$date';
```

Comment: A simple and effective solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you need to be aware of:

Your code is vurenable to SQL Injection.

You need to provide date in proper format. To do so I suggest using DateTime::createFromFormat function or strtotime. Let's do it with simplier way (strtotime)

```
<?php 

$parsedDate = strtotime($_GET['date']);

if (false !== $parsedDate) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET);
    $rows_sql = "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE added = '$date'";
} else {
    die("date is in wrong format");
}
```

Basicly it checks whether string can be converted to timestamp strtotime function and if it is possible (NOT FALSE) it will convert it with the format that DB can handle YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Often if you want to select from some time period then using operators like > < and BETWEEN may come handy. For example if you want to select the rows from whole day specified in GET date parameter

```
    if($date = strtotime($_GET['date'])) {
         $today = date('Y-m-d', $date);
         $rows_sql = "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE added BETWEEN '$today 00:00:00' AND '$today 23:59:59'";
    }
```